# Excel macro for creating pivot table

Tags: excel, pivot, vba

This is the recorded macro for creating a pivot table.
While running it I getting an error of:

> error 1004 unable to get the pivot  tables property  of worksheet class

```
    Range("_RallyQueryResultList[#All]").Select
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet30").PivotTables("PivotTable8").PivotCache. _
        CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet30!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable9" _
        , DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
    Sheets("Sheet30").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("Severity")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable9").PivotFields("Severity"), "Count of Severity", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("Owner")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable9").PivotFields("Requirement")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there actually a worksheet called `Sheet30`? If so, does the worksheet named `Sheet30` actually have any pivot tables?

Comment: Yes Phylogenesis .. There is a sheet 30 which has a pivot table